# How to produce outlined characters using command

Tags: fonts

How could I produce characters which are outlined, like below:

[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

It seemed like using some special command can add these outline to the character.

Comment: In general you need a font with that design but that looks like just overprinting `\textbf{f\hspace{-.3em}f}` or whatever space works in each case/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't think the `\hspace` approach will work in the examples of the `D` or the `E`.  However, overlaying a shifted `I` with the `D` or `E` just might.

Comment: This post reminds me when I was student and used a lot of times `IR` for real numbers. After I discovered `mathbb` my life changed!

Comment: @Sigur sure yes but they all look like overprinting of something rather than using an outline font

Answer (score 5):

Here I introduce `\varlet[stem]{letter}`, where `stem` is used if the stem is not to be taken as the original letter.  For example, in the case of `D` and `E`, the stem is a capital `I`.

The shift length is defined by `\shiftgap`. Thanks to barbara for suggesting it be measured in em (a horizontal font measure) and not ex (a vertical font measure).

Note that proper kerning following a `\varlet` is preserved, as in the case of `Var`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\shiftgap
\setlength\shiftgap{.11em}
\newcommand\varlet[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}\makebox[\wd0][l]{#2}\hspace{\dimexpr-\wd0+\shiftgap}#2%
  \else%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}\makebox[\wd0][l]{#1}\hspace{\dimexpr-\wd0+\shiftgap}#2%
  \fi%
}
\begin{document}
\itshape

\varlet[I]{D}
\varlet[I]{E}

\varlet{f}
\varlet{I}

\varlet{V}ar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is the result in `palatino`, with a `\shiftgap` of 0.115em:

[image]

Depending on what level of effort one wants to go through, one can customize the result further (here using slants):

```
\documentclass{article}
\newlength\shiftgap
\setlength\shiftgap{.11em}
\newcommand\varlet[2][\relax]{%
  \ifx\relax#1%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}\makebox[\wd0][l]{#2}\hspace{\dimexpr-\wd0+\shiftgap}#2%
  \else%
    \setbox0=\hbox{#2}\makebox[\wd0][l]{#1}\hspace{\dimexpr-\wd0+\shiftgap}#2%
  \fi%
}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newsavebox\foobox
\newcommand{\slantbox}[2][.5]{\mbox{%
        \sbox{\foobox}{#2}%
        \hskip\wd\foobox
        \pdfsave
        \pdfsetmatrix{1 0 #1 1}%
        \llap{\usebox{\foobox}}%
        \pdfrestore
}}
\begin{document}
\itshape
\varlet{V}ar \textup{versus}\par
\varlet[\kern.2em\raisebox{-.19pt}{\scalebox{1.03}{\slantbox[-.36]{I}}}]{V}ar
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you're using `ex` here for a horizontal adjustment.  `ex`, however, is a vertical font dimension.  it would be better to use the equivalent horizontal dimension, `em`, so it will be consistent regardless of font size.  (one shouldn't expect all font sizes to have the same relative proportions, vertical/horizontal.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton  Thank you barbara.  That is a good point.